# Transfer CSS value to DOM style attribute

Tags: jquery, css, dom, inline-styles

[image]

Let assume that the `#div1` has `padding-left` set to `50px`. By pressing a specific button the padding is changing to `0` with an animation:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#div1').animate({'padding-left':0}, 1000);
});
```

`#div2` is a block so it will change its size together with `#div1`.

Now the heart of the matter, I want to transfer the `#div2` `width` value to `<div id="div2" style="width: [HERE]"></div>` using jQuery. And then when `#div1` will be animated the `#div2` `width` will start to change its value in style attribute. I would like to see in browser developer tool how width of `#div2` is changing. 
Something like this:

Button released:

```
`<div id="div2" style="width: 200"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 211"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 224"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 235"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 244"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 250"></div>`
```

After one sec:

```
`<div id="div2" style="width: 250"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 250"></div>`
`<div id="div2" style="width: 250"></div>`
```

How can it be done ?

Comment: Do you mean [**like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWXQ4/)

Comment: @Macko, Your motives are somewhat vague. But it sounds like you just want to see what the current width of `div2` is during the animation. If so, this will print the width of `div2` to console for each step in the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/pND4X/ -- Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm it's hard to explain for me. English is not my native language. I want to see these steps - <div id="div2" style="width: [HERE]"></div>. Not in #div1 but in #div2 which is not animated by using jQuery

Comment: [**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/pND4X/2/)

Comment: @DavidLink It's yours to take, go ahead and answer it

Comment: Wait wait. I want to see changes in DOM not in console ;) <div id="div2" style="width: [HERE]"></div>

Comment: For what purpose? It's there, just not displayed inline

Comment: http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/ - I'm using this plugin, it detects attribute changes like style for example. With this one i don't need to use setinterval anymore. The whole idea is experimental, I'm looking for best solutions on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is [**something like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/pND4X/7/), which calculates the `auto` width, then updates the DOM style property using jQuery's `.attr`

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").animate(
        {
            marginLeft: 0
        }, {
            step: function(){
                $('#div2').width('auto');
                var width = $('#div2').width();
                $('#div2').attr('style', 'width: ' + width + 'px;');
            }
        }, 5000
    )
});
```

Overall this reallyisn't that useful because the browser inspector isn't an instantaneous change, so it jumps to the next values. Plus there is really no need for displaying the changes inline. If you want to display the change through another element (this shows immediate changes), then you can do so by using the same approach as [my updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/pND4X/2/) of David Link's fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly... this can be done with simple CSS Transitions.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="button">Animate</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
  -o-transition: width 1s ease;
  transition: width 1s ease;
  float:right;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.div1 {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 50px;
    float:right;
    width: 400px;
}
.div2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width:250px;
}
.no-padding {
    width: 600px;
}
.adjust-width{
  transition-delay: .8s;
  width:100%;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#button").click( function() {
    $(".div1").toggleClass("no-padding");
    $(".div2").toggleClass("adjust-width");
});
```

**DEMO:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/yinnette/VVe64/